# Binary representation of integers and floating point numbers: is there a monotonically increasing one-to-one correspondence?

Tags: floating-point, binary, integer

Dealing with a legacy system in which I need to store integers using a function which only accepts doubles as input, I came accross the following problem. We are given a binary number, for example:

00111111 11000000 00000000 00000000

If we represent it as an integer this number is 1069547520. If we represent it as an IEEE 754 floating point number it is 1.5. It is easy to see that there is a one-to-one correspondence between integers and IEEE 754 floating point numbers. My question is the following. Given two integers a and b, and their corresponding IEEE 754 floating point counterparts A and B, does a > b imply A > B?

I guess the answer is yes, but I lack strong arguments supporting it. Any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Positive IEEE 754 binary32 numbers map to increasing integers.

However:

- the IEEE 754 representation is sign-magnitude, so that negative binary32 numbers map to decreasing integers. If mapped to unsigned int32s, the negative floating-point numbers map above the positive floating-point numbers (and if you are going to bit-twiddle floating-point numbers, you may as well map them to unsigned int32s).
- IEEE 754 has `+0.0` and `-0.0`, which are equal for some floating-point definition of “equal” but map to very different integers (respectively `0` and, if mapping to a signed 32-bit int type, `INT_MIN`).
- IEEE 754 has several representations of NaN, which map to different integers.
- this assumes that floating-point and integer representations have the same endianness. There are many advantages in giving them the same endianness, but ARM, to cite an example, has historically been doing strange things with endianness, so I should point this out.

Comment: I suppose it is the same with IEEE 754 binary64, right?

Comment: @joanlofe Yes, the same applies to binary64 and 64-bit integers.

Comment: Another way of saying what Pascal said is that:

For floats of the same sign:
1.Adjacent floats have adjacent integer representations 
2.Incrementing the integer representation of a float moves to the next representable float, moving away from zero 

NaNs and infinities and negatives and subnormals (some floating-point units flush very small numbers to zero) can all complicate this.

I go into this in more detail here:

http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/stupid-float-tricks-2/